# How to select a fixed number of adjacent columns starting from N column in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with about 50 columns of products starting from column "T"

and I want to select columns from Column "T" and 40 columns on the right but I am confused how can I achieve this

should I rely on something like

```
Columns("T:(number of columns)").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
Public Sub SelectColumnsWithStartAndOffset()
    Dim strFirstColumn As String, lngOffset As Long, strLastColumn As String

    strFirstColumn = "T"
    lngOffset = 40

    With Sheet1
        strLastColumn = Split(.Range(strFirstColumn & "1").Offset(0, lngOffset).Address, "$")(1)
        .Range(strFirstColumn & ":" & strLastColumn).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

You may just need to adjust the offset 1 (give or take) to make sure the correct amount of columns are selected.

I hope that works for you.